# How to prevent JsonConvert.SerializeObject from adding $id

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this code:

```
     JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {

                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None

            };

            var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result[0], settings);
```

No matter what I do, SerializeObject insists to add the $id to the json result.
How do I make the $id disappear?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that this Json.NET is a real junk.

Ended up using this:

```
 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          var obj =   ser.Serialize(result[0]);
```